# Equality condition for Araki–Lieb–Thirring inequality

Tags: inequalities, hilbert-spaces, traces, hermitian

I'd like to have the equality condition in the Araki–Lieb–Thirring inequality 
$$\operatorname{Tr} [(BAB)^r]\leq \operatorname{Tr} [(B^{r}A^{r}B^{r})],$$
valid for $A,B$ semidefinite positive and $r\geq1$ (I'm interested in the case $r=2$).
Any clue? I didn't find the proof of it yet, I guess it would be a good start!

As explained in comment, finding the equality condition for the inequality $$\operatorname{Tr} [X^2]\leq \operatorname{Tr} [XX^\dagger]$$
is sufficient!

It is the inequality n°13 of
[Lieb and Thirring - Inequalities for the moments of the Eigenvalues of the Schrödinger Hamiltonian and their relation to Sobolev inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#cite_note-19).

Comment: At least for $r=2$ this can be proven with the inequality $$\operatorname{Tr} [X^2]\leq \operatorname{Tr} [XX^\dagger],$$ with $X=B^2A$.
It is (4) of https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1704727?class=pdf, proven for instance here:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063049/pdf/pnas01544-0068.pdf
But the equality condition is not clear for me...

Comment: You are asking for the equality case in the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality $\langle X, X^*\rangle \leq \|X\|^2$ for the scalar product $\langle \cdot ,\cdot\rangle = Tr(\cdot (\cdot)^*)$... so the answer is that $Tr(X^2) = Tr(X X^*)$ if and only if $X=X^*$, so (if $X=B^2 A$ for positive $A,B$) if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: Yes, this is what  found using the Schur decomposition, thanks!